# Retrieving images from server using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im trying to learn AJAX. In my WAMPSERVER www.directory i have a file called IMAGES. inside that file there is an image called logo.png. Im trying to retrieve this image from server using this code

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
       var response = xmlhttp.responseText;


var img=document.createElement("img");
img.src=response;
var myDiv=document.getElementById("one");
myDiv.appendChild(img);


     }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("get","images/logo.png",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onclick=loadXMLDoc
```

In chrome it throws error about cross origin or something (restriction). But in firefox it does append image but without src and it throws error "not well formed".
If i change code a bit to only innerHTMl to said div and using

```
xmlhttp.open("get","images/change.txt",true);
```

it works.

So, what is the right way to retrieve image from server? Also , lets say i have more images in "images" folder , how could i retrieve them all?

Comment: What does `change.txt` contain? And why are you AJAXing an image when `document.createElement("img").src ='images/logo.png'` would just work fine.

Comment: change.txt contains "<p style="color:red">My name is CHANGE</p>" , im trying to AJAX it bcs as i said , i would like to retrieve all images from images folder and add it to website. ALso i would add images to the server which would result in ajax automaticky getting all images and updating website

Comment: If your images are in your `www` folder then they are already on your server, also if they are not on your server an AJAX request wont help. Also you dont need to **get** the images technically but more just a reference to their location. A @JosephtheDreamer pointed out, for each image you want just set its src as he has in his comment.

Comment: well... and how would i get the reference to images on server ? Especially when there are more images and more of images would be added eventually. Im not very good with server-side.

Comment: you can just use html `<img src="images/logo.png" alt="">` and replace `logo.png` with the name of the image.

Comment: Yes i can do that... But as i said , i will be uploading more images to the database. And if i use AJAX it will automaticly update website.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use javascript to fetch the images. Just create the HTML tag and let HTML and the browser do their job. I don't mean to be rude in any way its just that this is the right answer to your question. If you just ask to learn about AJAX please provide a question more relevant to AJAX functionality.

Comment: Ok. But how could i achieve my goal? I mean as i said i will be adding pictures to the database and i want website to be automaticly updated. Thats the reason i thought ajax would be fine.

Comment: You should use a server side language like asp.net, php, java or python with which you have access to local db or folder where you store your images. With that you should list all files and return the names of them to the requesting ajax call. Then in the ajax call you can loop through all files and create html img tags for each one of them. What application server are you using?